PgBouncer - Trying to connect to ipv6 localhost
I have postgresql 12 and pgboucner 1.22-1. I am getting the following warning message in pgbouncer.log constantly:
WARNING sbuf_connect failed to connect to [::1]:5432: No route to host
I have in section databases:
* = host=localhost port=5432
and in /etc/hosts both 127.0.0.1 and [::1] are mapped to localhost.
How can I get rid of this message and why is pgbouncer trying to connect to postgres via ipv6 instead of ipv4 ?
--- Update ---
Seems that the issue is that postgres does not listen on ::1
In pg_hba.conf I have the following line
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
but still when I try to connect to postgres with --host ::1 I get
Is the server running on host "::1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
